# kotlin factory for subclass

Tags: kotlin, constructor, annotations, factory

I have a class that needs a factory which when provided with a sample value of a subclass, will create a new object with the class of the sub class.  Eg

```
open class Base(val i:Int){
    fun <T:Base>factory(sample:T, n:Int) = Base(i) // need sample." invoke constructor" (i) as T
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this work when called with any subclass of Base as a a parameter without needing to add the boilerplate, or reflection beyond that available to KotlinJS to override the factory for every future subclass?

Comment: You would need to use reflection to instantiate the class, and have a class contract that every subclass of `Base` must have a constructor with just that one `n` parameter. This could not be enforced at compile time, so you'd have to throw an exception when such a constructor is missing from a class.

Comment: @Tenfour04 ... yes, that is where i got too as well, can't see a way around it, was hoping that perhaps using an annotation.  Pity because overriding fun factory in each subclass becomes boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
open class Base(val i: Int) {

    fun <T : Base> factory(sample: T, @Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") n: Int): Base {
        @Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE") val constructor = sample::class.js

        return js("new constructor(n)") as Base
    }

    override fun toString() = "Base($i)"
}

class Derived(i: Int) : Base(i) {

    override fun toString() = "Derived($i)"
}


fun main() {
    println(Base(10).factory(Derived(20), n = 5))  // "Derived(5)"
}
```

Comment: I was really after a solution that uses no more reflection than is available to js, but at least this does give a solution for js, which means if I use multiplatform with an expect/actual i can have jvm as well as js code.  So using this for JS means only native is unsatisfied at this time.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you'd better use reified type parameter, so your factory will not need a `sample` parameter.
Secondly, If your factory will return an object of generic type, then you will not need to override it in subclasses - it will return instances of desired types.

But I don't see a way how to do it without [reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html):

```kotlin
open class Base (val i: Int) {
    inline fun <reified T : Base> factory(n: Int): T {
        val kClass = T::class
        val constructor = kClass.constructors.find { it.parameters.size == 1 && it.parameters[0].type == Int::class }
            ?: throw RuntimeException("Constructor with single Int parameter was not found for ${kClass.qualifiedName} class")
        return constructor.call(n)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
open class Derived(i: Int) : Base(i)
open class Derived2(i: Int) : Derived(i)

//any subclass of Base or Base itself when called on instance of Base
val base = Base(1)
val a: Base = base.factory(1) //or val a = base.factory<Base>(1)
val b: Derived = base.factory(1)
val c: Derived2 = base.factory(1)

//any subclass of Base or Base itself when called on any instance of Base subclass
val derived2 = Derived2(1)
val a1: Base = derived2.factory(1)
val b1: Derived = derived2.factory(1)
val c1: Derived2 = derived2.factory(1)
```

Comment: This answer starts badly with the 'use a reified type parameter' to avoid having a parameter to specify the type.  The whole idea is that the factory produces a clone of a *supplied type*, not an instance of the current class!  (every problem becomes a nail) If you need an instance of the current class, why not just instance one :)  The code supplied does provide workable code for calling a constructor using reflection, and if that code is applied to 'sample' instead of the current class it is workable when resorting to reflection, but the goal was to avoid resorting to reflection.